# issue with calling function inside the other function

Tags: javascript

I am getting a response as  "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined " error  while calling deleteButtons() function inside displayCart() function. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
  function displayCart() {
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);


let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
```

//  console.log(cartItems);---pulling data from localstorage

```
console.log(cartItems); 

if(cartItems && productContainer) {

    productContainer.innerHTML ='';
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
    productContainer.innerHTML +=   
        `
        <div class="products">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>

         <span>${item.name}</span>            


    <div class="price">$${item.price},00</div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <ion-icon name="caret-back-circle-outline">Remove</ion-icon>

        <span>${item.incart}</span> 
        <ion-icon name="caret-forward-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
    $${item.incart * item.price},00 
    </div>
    </div>
        `
    ;
    });

    productContainer.innerHTML += 
        `
        <div class="basketTotalContainer">
        <h4 class="basketTotalTitle"> Basket Total </h4>
        <h4 class ="basketTotal"> 
            $${cartCost},00
        </h4> 
    </div>

        `;          
 }
```

deleteButtons(); 
    }

function deleteButtons() {

```
let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon'); 
let productName;
let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers')
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');   
console.log(cartItems);

for(let i=0; i < 10; i++)    
{

    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');    
console.log(productName);
console.log(cartItems[productName].price + " " + cartItems[productName].incart);
localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers',productNumbers - cartItems[productName].incart);
localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - (cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].incart));
delete cartItems[productName];
localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));      
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser and find out what `deleteButtons` contains. Where is your JS in relation to your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 things to consider:

1. The class name mismatch `.product` when it should be `.products`
2. You are using an arbitrary fixed number (10) to iterate over a dynamically allocated collection of elements.

Since the collection is dynamic you should use the size of it in order to know when to stop your loop, in this case by using `deleteButtons.length`

Se the runnable example below:

```js
let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.products ion-icon')

for(let i=0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`This is the deleteButtons #${i}`);
  });
}
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
ion-icon { cursor: pointer; padding 1em; margin: 1em 0; border: 1px solid #333 }
```

```html
<hr/>
<div class="products">
  <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline">A</ion-icon>
  <span>${item.name}</span>
  <div class="price">$${item.price},00</div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <ion-icon name="caret-back-circle-outline">Remove</ion-icon>
    <span>${item.incart}</span> 
    <ion-icon name="caret-forward-circle-outline">X</ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="total">
  $${item.incart * item.price},00
</div>
```

Comment: It’s easier to just use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) or [`forEach` with `Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: How is that `easier`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');`

To

`let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.products ion-icon');`

Your main class looks like `products` instead of `product` from your code.

Comment: Even tho, `ion-icon` is not really an offically supported tagname.

Comment: It could be a part of some framework or could be custom elements as well. That is specific implementation detail so I didn't focus on that.

Comment: Well  yes, in the example it is used as element.